# Inexplicable Mesh Deformation

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, armature

I built an armature from scratch today, and I'm running into a very strange deformation problem. The mesh is doing only what I can refer to as "crunching" rather than rotating like a soft tube. This glove mesh has all transformations applied, all bones have the same roll of 0 degrees, and my bone modifiers don't impact this crunching effect at all... any ideas?

[image: related pic]

EDIT: Here's a link to the file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U0a0FS5hxBwtaG10bofRPGFEeY-0SLZ_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you link a file?

Comment: Here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U0a0FS5hxBwtaG10bofRPGFEeY-0SLZ_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You do not in fact have all transforms applied.  If we look at the glove object, aka Cube.014_Cube.007:

[image]

Location isn't applied (which isn't a biggie, but it can be a problem for some operations.)  More importantly, rotation isn't applied.

Unshown, but location isn't applied on the armature either.

So let's apply all transforms on glove object and armature, and then re-autoweight (because transforms can affect autoweights.)  Hmm, still not right.  Because your normals on your glove object are backwards, which we can see by enabling face orientation on overlays:

[image]

So we'll enter edit mode and recalculate normals on that mesh, and then repeat our autoweights:

[image]

Everything looks dandy to me now.